# MPMediaPlayerController Error: timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MusicUIService

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mpmediapickercontroller

Developing for iOS7, I get the following error:

```
<MPRemoteMediaPickerController: 0x175338b0> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MusicUIService
```

This is the code I use to instantiate and present the media picker controller.

```
- (void)showMediaPicker {

    localMediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];

    localMediaPicker.delegate = self;
    localMediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;

    // show media picker
    [self presentViewController:localMediaPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

I swear this worked for previous versions of iOS but I cannot figure out what the issue is. Has anyone else come across this issue?

Comment: This is not an xcode question. Helping @H2CO3 in his personal battle ;-)

Comment: lol Sorry, you're right. My fault! @flexaddicted

Comment: No problem Kevin. Thanks for replying.